# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to init UIActionSheet in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiactionsheet

My program compiles successfully, but when I press the button, it crashes. Here's the viewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate{

@IBOutlet var button:UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(AnyObject) {
    let choice = UIActionSheet(title: "Select source", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles:"camera", "libary")
    choice.showInView(self.view)
}
}
```

The error appears on this line:

```
let choice = UIActionSheet(title: "Select source", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles:"camera", "library")
```

And here's error text:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)**

I tried to switch let to var, ran it on different simulators, but the result is same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried, but unable to figure out the exception. Finally I got a solution like this :

```
  var myActionSheet:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()

        var title : String? = "Select Source"
        myActionSheet.title  = title
            myActionSheet.delegate = self
        myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("camera")
        myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Library")
        myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")

        myActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 2 
        myActionSheet.showInView(self.view)
```

***UIActionSheet Delegate***

```
func actionSheet(myActionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
        println("the index is %d", buttonIndex)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Btw, I changed "var" to "let" and it works too!

Comment: Hmm, actionSheet(myActionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) doesn't work. Code is the same, but I add these lines to the class implementation.

Comment: Check the delegates properly . ran into this code and then only i posted

Comment: I missed "myActionSheet.delegate = self" line. Now everything works fine. Thank you

Comment: I was having the same issue and random crashes when i would NSLog() the view of the controller running the code. It looks like the constructor with parameters has some kind of serious bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end otherButtonTitles parameters with nil. For example, in your case it should be:

```
otherButtonTitles:"camera", "libary", nil
```

It is not Swift specific, it is the same in objective-c too.